# Dynamically change android's accent color

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, themes

I set Android's accent color to grey, so it would look normal in any theme (light or dark). And gray works great for edit control for example, but it turns out that is also used in alert cancel button's text. So now it looks fine in light theme, but very bad in the dark one.

How can I change `colorAccent` for Android dynamically from Xamarin.Forms app?

[image]
[image]

Edit: Here is [my theme changing code](https://github.com/maxkoshevoi/CalendarToolbox/blob/35d20e023aa695c1105a2f03fd5da2e1596e03cb/CalendarToolbox/CalendarToolbox/Themes/ThemeHelper.cs) as of now. (I'm not using `AppThemeBinding` since this approach allows to more than two themes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

1. All you have to put accent (or any other) color for light theme in `MyApp.Android\Resources\values\colors.xml` and for dark theme in `MyApp.Android\Resources\values-night\colors.xml`. Then reference that color by name in your theme in `styles.xml` `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>`.
   Now, when device would switch to dark theme accent color also would change.
2. Now. What if you have manual theme control in your app? You can force Android to display color for light or dark theme. Add similar interface to the shared project:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Core.Models.InterplatformCommunication
{
    public interface INightModeManager
    {
        NightModeStyle DefaultNightMode { get; set; }
    }

    public enum NightModeStyle
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An unspecified mode for night mode.
        /// </summary>
        Unspecified = -100,

        /// <summary>
        /// Mode which uses the system's night mode setting to determine if it is night or not.
        /// </summary>
        FollowSystem = -1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Night mode which uses always uses a light mode, enabling non-night qualified resources regardless of the time.
        /// </summary>
        No = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Night mode which uses always uses a dark mode, enabling night qualified resources regardless of the time.
        /// </summary>
        Yes = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Night mode which uses a dark mode when the system's 'Battery Saver' feature is enabled, otherwise it uses a 'light mode'.
        /// </summary>
        AutoBattery = 3
    }
}
```

3. Add this implementation in Android project. Setting `AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode` forces the app to load resources for light or dark theme without restarting the app.

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NightModeManager))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Dependences
{
    public class NightModeManager : INightModeManager
    {
        public NightModeStyle DefaultNightMode
        {
            get => (NightModeStyle)AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode;
            set => AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = (int)value;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Add this logic when changing theme of your app (`AppTheme` is a custom enum):

```cs
private static void UpdateNativeStyle(AppTheme selectedTheme)
        {
            NightModeStyle style = selectedTheme switch
            {
                AppTheme.Dark => NightModeStyle.Yes,
                AppTheme.Light => NightModeStyle.No,
                AppTheme.FollowSystem => NightModeStyle.FollowSystem,
                _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported theme"),
            };

            var nightModeManager = DependencyService.Get<INightModeManager>();
            nightModeManager.DefaultNightMode = style;
        }
```

More info about this:

- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94
- https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Forms, we could use **[DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/)** to call native method. Fortunately, Android document provide the method [setLocalNightMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setLocalNightMode(int)) to modify the local DarkMode. We should note that this mehtod can not modify the configure of **Settings** for the Mobile.

Now we can create a `IDarkModeService` interface:

```
public interface IDarkModeService
{
    void SetDarkMode(bool value);
}
```

Then implement its method in Android solution:

```
public class DarkModeService : IDarkModeService
{
    public void SetDarkMode(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            
     MainActivity.instance.Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightYes);
            MainActivity.instance.Recreate();
        }
        else
        {
       
     MainActivity.instance.Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo);
            MainActivity.instance.Recreate();
        }
      
    }
}
```

Here we need to create a static `instance` from **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity instance { set; get; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        instance = this;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
   
}
```

}

And not forgetting to add configure inside `styles.xml` to make the app support **DarkMode**:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"></style>
```

Last, we could call the dependency method in Xamarin Forms as follows:

```
private async void ShowDialog_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
}

private void SetDarkMode_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IDarkModeService>().SetDarkMode(true);
}

private void CancelDarkMode_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IDarkModeService>().SetDarkMode(false);
}
```

The effect:

[image]

==================================Update==================================

If need to custom style of each **Theme**, you could exchange **Theme** on runtime.

First, you could store a Theme flag(***DarkMode***) in Xamrin Forms:

```
private void SetDarkMode_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Preferences.Set("DarkMode", true);
    DependencyService.Get<IDarkModeService>().SetDarkMode(true);
}

private void CancelDarkMode_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Preferences.Set("DarkMode", false);
    DependencyService.Get<IDarkModeService>().SetDarkMode(false);
}
```

Then add each Theme style inside **styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   
  </style>

  <style name="DayTheme" parent="MainTheme">
   
  </style>

  <style name="NightTheme" parent="MainTheme" >
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/positiveBtnStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/negativeBtnstyle</item>
  </style>

  <!--style of sure button-->
  <style name="positiveBtnStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>
  </style>

  <!--style of cancel button-->
  <style name="negativeBtnstyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#999999</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Last, change the Theme before create view in **MainActivity.cs**:

```
public static MainActivity instance { set; get; }
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    instance = this;

    var darkMode = Preferences.Get("DarkMode", false);
    if (darkMode)
    {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.NightTheme);
    }
    else
    {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.DayTheme);
    }

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Now we could see the color style of button will change:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer, but this is not what I need. In your example accent color doesn't change (color of alert's Ok button stays the same). I already have functionality to change theme in my app. The only thing I cannot change is accent color

Comment: PS: Added code from my app in question description. Maybe it will help

Comment: @МаксимКошевой Okey, I will check that. If update answer will mark here.

Comment: @МаксимКошевой I have updated the answer, you could have a look when you have time. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just noticed that in your example you recreate the view on theme change. So, if user changes theme, it will essentially restart the application (all unsaved changes and opened pages will be lost)? That's not good since on android 10+ dark theme can be on schedule and can be activated automatically. So if application will just restart in the middle of something, that won't be good user experience. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something, never manually recreated the view before, so don't know what to expect there

Comment: @МаксимКошевой Okey, you're right. It should be a problem if need to recreate the View. I will research that , if good solution will update here.

Answer (score 0):

you can't, because the accent color is defined in the theme and themes are read-only. I assume that dynamically means programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I meant programmatically. Ok, so can I define several themes in android project and change them programmatically then? PS: Added code from my app in question description. Maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

As as side note, after setting:

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = ...
```

you need to recreate the activity to apply changes to current Page:

```
activity.Recreate();
```

For example, if you are using [CrossCurrentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) plugin for Xamarin, you can do:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Recreate();
```

Comment: Everything works for me without recreating the activity. What SDK are you targeting?

Comment: API Level 29 - Android 10